# How to achieve this alignment

Tags: css

I understand some basic CSS but I currently struggly to achieve the following aligning of 4 elements.

I have 2 rows of 2 elements. In every row the left element is aligned left and the right element is aligned right.

```
MediumSizedElement1.............................ShortEL2
VerryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3...........MediumSizedElement4
```

I already achieved the general Position, but greatest struggle is, that the ShortEL2 items likes to align itself with the 4th Element below it.

```
MediumSizedElement1..................ShortEL2...........
VerryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3...........MediumSizedElement4
```

Please help me to achieve the first picture.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mre]. Show us the code you currently have.

Comment: iam considering it as table ...add  float:right to the second column <td> ...if not please give the code snippet

Comment: you should add your html to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS grid to the rescue!

```css
.grid-host {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}

.grid-host :nth-child(even) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-host">
  <div>MediumSizedElement1</div>
  <div>ShortEL2</div>
  <div>VerryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3</div>
  <div>MediumSizedElement4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer is a combination of `float` and `text-align`, although the specific may depend on your exact situation. One option would be to place each element into a block-type tag like `div` and apply two different styles. So, you'd have something like this.

HTML

```html
<div class="left">MediumSizedElement1</div>
<div class="right">ShortEL2</div>
<div class="left">VerryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3</div>
<div class="right">MediumSizedElement4</div>
```

CSS

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

The float will make your `div`s move to the left and right of the parent element, and the `text-align`s will make the text move to the left and right edges of the `div`s (which may be needed if you've applied widths to them - in your example it looks like you may have the two elements on the right set to the same width, so the text is being left-aligned within a right-aligned block, leaving extra space on the right of your text).

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to achieve:

1. using `table` layout

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr>td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>MediumSizedElement1</td>
    <td>ShortEL2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>erryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3</td>
    <td>MediumSizedElement4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2. using `flexbox`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div,p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>MediumSizedElement1</p>
    <p>ShortEL2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <p>VerryyyyyyyyyyLongElement3</p>
      <p>MediumSizedElement4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!